# stack implementation error in brackets problem

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I am solving a LeetCode problem [20. Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/description/):

> Given a string `s` containing just the characters `'('`, `')'`, `'{'`, `'}'`, `'['` and `']'`, determine if the input string is valid.
>
> An input string is valid if:
>
> - Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
> - Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.
> - Every close bracket has a corresponding open bracket of the same type.

Many testcases have been passed. It just fails for `"{[]}"`

My submission: https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/submissions/1202908225/

#### My code

```
typedef struct node
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL;

int isEmpty(node *head)
{
    return head == NULL;
}

node *pop(node *head)
{
    node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
    return head;
}

node *push(node *head, char a)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->data = a;
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data = a;
        temp->next = head;
        return temp;
    }
}

char peek(node *head)
{
    return head->data;
}

bool isValid(char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[')
        {
            head = push(head, s[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isEmpty(head)) // Check if stack is empty
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((s[i] == ')' && peek(head) == '(') ||
                     (s[i] == '}' && peek(head) == '{') ||
                     (s[i] == ']' && peek(head) == '['))
            {
                head = pop(head);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return isEmpty(head); // Check if stack is empty after processing all characters
}
```

I can't figure out why the code isn't working for this specific test case.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Aside: in `push()` you shouldn't need to make a special case when `head == NULL`. If you study the code carefully you can see that the four lines in the `else` code block have exactly the same result as the code in the `if` block.

Comment: Please don't change the code to keep pace with comments and make it a shifting-sand question. Just post the code that fails on Leete.

Comment: A linked list stack implementation is quite overkill for this problem. It already specifies input constraints, guaranteeing that the maximum string length is 10000. That's a perfectly reasonable for a fixed-size array of chars representing your stack storage. You don't have to worry about thread-safety here, so you can just have a static array. _e.g._ https://godbolt.org/z/bej78rTPa

Comment: Sidenote: [Should I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't clean up your linked list before the function returns, and that the next time the `isValid` function is called, the previous list is still there -- and possibly not empty, influencing the result of that next call.

To solve this, you should not define `head` as a global variable, but as a variable local to `isValid`, and also avoid leaking memory, by freeing the memory you still have allocated for nodes in the list.

So, to keep the changes to your code at a minimum, we can make it work like this:

```
// Add this function for removing all nodes from a list
node* clear(node *head) {
    while (head) {
        head = pop(head);
    }
    return NULL;
}

bool isValid(char *s)
{
    node *head = NULL; // Local variable!
    int len = strlen(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[')
        {
            head = push(head, s[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isEmpty(head)) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if ((s[i] == ')' && peek(head) == '(') ||
                     (s[i] == '}' && peek(head) == '{') ||
                     (s[i] == ']' && peek(head) == '['))
            {
                head = pop(head);
            }
            else
            {
                head = clear(head); // Avoid leaking memory
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    bool result = isEmpty(head);
    head = clear(head); // Avoid leaking memory
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: yes it worked, But i'm new to c can you please explain it in a simpler way why it worked when head is local

Comment: LeetCode runs multiple test cases. When the previous test case returned `false` because the list was not empty at the bottom `return` statement, then the current test case will start with a non-empty list (still having the nodes from the previous run of `isValid`). This will lead to wrong results. If you clean up your list (which you should do), you could in theory keep `head` as a global, but it is better practice to have it local, and it would then even have worked without cleanup.